# Are these three default constructors equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, class, standards, default-constructor, noexcept

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct A1 {
    T t;

    // implicitly-declared default constructor
};

template<typename T>
struct A2 {
    T t;

    // explicitly-declared default constructor without noexcept
    A2() = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct A3 {
    T t;

    // explicitly-declared default constructor with noexcept
    A3() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value) = default;
};
```

**Are these three default constructors equivalent in C++?**

Comment: The first two are equivalent as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78072843/12002570). The third one's exception specification depends on whether expression evaluates to true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these is equivalent to each other.

First, `A1<T>` is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) whereas `A2<T>` and `A3<T>` are not. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MeTz4bGav). The definition of aggregate has varied across standards, and this is an aggregate (again) in C++20... so if you support older standards, `A1<T>` will have very different powers in each.

This has a strong effect on where and how these can be constructed. If one can construct a `T`, one can construct an `A1<T>` but not necessarily an `A2<T>` or `A3<T>`. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zbEG7PvEd).

So `A1<T>` varies from the others in whether you can construct it at all.

`A2<T>` and `A3<T>` differ in whether the default constructor is `noexcept`. `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v` does not check only if a value is nothrow constructible but also destructible. Whereas the defaulted declaration without noexcept specification only checks constructors. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EsW57ErfY). (This is [LWG 2116](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2116).)

Answer (score 7):

Two and three are equivalent; three is just error-prone and redundant.

The first one is equivalent in terms of constructor functionality. However, because it doesn't have any explicitly declared (even defaulted) constructor, the struct is an aggregate, which the other two aren't.

Comment: The question is about `noexcept specification`. I don't see how this answers the question in an authoritative way.

Comment: @Alan Do you mean you expect quotes from the standard supporting my assertion?

Comment: The question asks if they are equivalent, not only in noexcept?

Comment: @JeffGarrett As per my reading also, the question is asking about whether the ctors are equivalent in the context of *noexcept specification* and not whether one is aggregate or not or how object of that type be initialized etc.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I read it differently. I see "are these constructors equivalent" (in the title and bolded in the body) and no question specifically about are they equivalent with respect to noexcept or any other particular factor.

Comment: @user12002570 I didn't read it that way, but your answer being the accepted one suggests you guess the OP's intent better.

Answer (score 5):

> Are these three default constructors equivalent in C++?

Yes the default ctors are equivalent in the context of `noexcept specification`.

This can be seen from [default ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

> **The implicitly-declared (or defaulted on its first declaration) default constructor has an exception specification as described in** dynamic exception specification(until C++17) **noexcept specification**(since C++17).

So we move onto [noexcept specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> Every function in C++ is either non-throwing or potentially throwing:
>
> - **potentially-throwing functions are**:
>
>   - functions declared without noexcept specifier **except for**
>
>     - **default constructors**, copy constructors, move constructors **that are implicitly-declared or defaulted on their first declaration** unless
>
>       - **a constructor for a** base or **member that the implicit definition of the constructor would call is potentially-throwing** (see below)

Comment: I think no matter whether `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value` is `true` or `false`, these three default ctors seem equivalent.

Comment: @xmllmx Source?

Comment: Just my intuition: if `T`'s default ctor is potentially throwing, then `A1()` & `A2()` must be also potentially throwing; otherwise, if `T`'s default ctor is non-throwing, then `A1()` & `A2()` must also be non-throwing. So, I think these three should be equivalent.

Comment: @user12002570 , you didn't quote the text after <<unless>>: "a constructor for a base or **member** that the implicit definition of the constructor would call is potentially-throwing (see below)". So I would say that all 3 constructors have the same signature (C++17 and later)?

Comment: @xmllmx So in other words `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value)` have no say in deciding whether it is throwing or non-throwing? I also see the phrase *"defaulted special member functions"* in the last quoted reference in my answer. So the three seem to be equivalent.

Comment: @user12002570, I think if `T`'s default ctor is potentially throwing, then `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value` should be `false`; otherwise `true`.

Comment: "I think if T's default ctor is potentially throwing, then std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value should be false; otherwise true" This is false.

Comment: "Just my intuition: if T's default ctor is potentially throwing, then A1() & A2() must be also potentially throwing; otherwise, if T's default ctor is non-throwing, then A1() & A2() must also be non-throwing." A1 doesn't have a constructor being an aggregate. And as mentioned "T's default ctor potentially throwing" is not (only) what the type trait tests.